# How to save image to the database after it is scanned

Tags: c#-4.0

I have developed a windows application to scan images.After the image is scanned i want to save it directly to the database not in local machine...The code which i have used is as follows

```
try
{
    String str = string.Empty;
    WIA.CommonDialogClass scanner;
    ImageFile imageObject;

    scanner = new CommonDialogClass();
    imageObject = scanner.ShowAcquireImage
        (WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, 
        WiaImageIntent.ColorIntent,
        WiaImageBias.MinimizeSize,
        ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid.ToString("B"), 
        false, 
        true,
        true);

    str = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    str = str.Replace("/", "");
    str = str.Replace(":", "");
    Directory.CreateDirectory("D:\\scanned1");
    //            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("File Extension = {0}\n
    //\nFormat = {1}", imageObject.FileExtension, imageObject.FormatID));
    imageObject.SaveFile(@"D:\scanned1\lel" + str + ".jpg");
    MessageBox.Show("Scanning Done");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please check if the scanner is connected properly.");
}
```

Instead of saving it to D drive i want to save it to database.....How can i do it?Plz reply...

Comment: What is your problem? Do you have problems with the db-interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got no idea what "ImageFile" is really, but there should be a way to transform it into the byte array (byte[]). Afterwards you would need to insert that array to varbinary field in your sql.
something like this:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MyTable (myvarbinarycolumn) VALUES (@myvarbinaryvalue)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@myvarbinaryvalue", SqlDbType.VarBinary, myarray.length).Value = myarray;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

ofc sqlcommand should be opened and valid. 
myarray is of type byte[]

Comment: Hey  Georgy Smirnov..The image is saved in .jpg format...i need to convert it to byte format

Comment: Take a look at http://edulorenzo.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/cast-wia-imagefile-to-system-drawing-image/ There you can see, how to convert it to a byte-array